# Linux: Stopping tar command?

Tags: linux, tar

Uh I badly messed up today, I was going to backup my whole website folder (public_html) and didn't realize that it was 24GB, now it's eating up disk usage and I have no idea how to stop it. The command I used was:

```
tar -cvpzf  /home/mywebsite/public_html/backup.tar.gz /home/mywebsite/public_html/
```

I deleted the existing backup.tar.gz from the directory but the command is still running and is still eating up disk space (even though the .tar.gz file no longer exists). How do I stop this?

Comment: Kill the tar process?

Comment: `kill -9 \`pgrep tar\``

Comment: @Behe Would it clear up the disk usage used by the command? I was hesitating to do this because of it. (EDIT: Ah, yes it did!)

Comment: It is about killing a Unix process. Being it a tar does not have any relevant derivations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```sh
ps -ef | grep tar
```

Figure out the tar command's PID, then kill it with.

```sh
kill <pid>
```

For instance, `kill 1234` if it is PID 1234. Wait a bit, and if it hasn't died gracefully from that then hit it with the sledgehammer.

```sh
kill -9 <pid>
```

Alternatively, you could kill all running tar commands with a single command.

```sh
pkill tar

# if necessary
pkill -9 tar
```

Either way, once the process dies, the disk space will clear up. Deleting the file didn't help because a running process still has the file open. Files aren't truly deleted until they're removed *and* they're not open in any process.

Comment: Thank you!! I ran this command and it immediately stopped the whole thing. The disk usage was also cleared up!